# Craftsmanship of Bionic Respiratory System?

Tags: equipment, dark-heresy-2e

I was reading about the cybernetics available in Dark Heresy 2E and found this for Bionic Respiratory System:

> Good bionic lungs count as a full life support system—if for any reason the user’s own respiratory system fails, his bionic lungs keep his blood oxygenated—and can be designed to be unnoticeable if desired.

The text is ambiguous as to what "full life support" means in terms of mechanics. Would this allow the character to survive in a vacuum for an extended period, or is it up to the GM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I play and GM a lot of Deathwatch but have never played Dark Heresy so take my answer with a pinch of salt.

It is quite clearly worded, if the players respiratory system fails it keeps the players blood oxygenated, that is all.

It breaths for you so yes it means you can breath in space but that is all, the cold of space will likely kill you fastest with a long list of other issues such as radiation and micro asteroids helping to end you.

As reference a Space marine must be in his sealed power armour to survive in the vacuum of space, if an attack does enough damage to overcome the armour even if toughness negated the rest his armour is no longer sealed.
Unless repaired they must test every round to avoid the affects of space.

Detailed rules for functioning in space can be found in the Deathwatch book "Arc of Souls". It is all about space hulks and has a section about compartments exposed to space.

Comment: I agree with your points, but the point of bionic lungs is that they replace the character's organic lungs; they don't have extra lungs, just robotic ones.

Comment: @PresidentialPenguin thats a matter of role play, you have 2 lungs, a space marine has 3 . How many are replaced are up to you and the GM

Comment: I'll just say that, rules-wise, it means that the character can ignore environmental hazards, and will only stop breathing if he must use the life support for too long (i.e. an hour) or the system is damaged through critical effects.

Comment: Also worth noting is that in Dark Heresy 2e, your armour can be eventually be completely degraded by taking too much damage. It's analogous to the Space Marine getting hit while in the void and soaking the damage with his TB but not his armor, where each time damage overcomes armour you lose 1AV on that location until it's gone.